# Exif date taken for multiple photos - Python

Tags: python, windows, date, photo, exif

My Exif code failed in my project so the photos came out without a "date taken" field. Luckly ive saved them with the date taken as the tittle eg. "-Forward14-07-2021-08-23-25.jpg". I have thousands of photos like this. I can add that individually using this python code.

```
from datetime import datetime
import piexif

s = "13"
m = "17"
h = "09"


dd = "14"
mm = "07"
yyyy = "2021"
name = "-Forward"

filename = str(name) + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(yyyy) + "-" + str(h) + "-" + str(m) + "-" + str(s) + ".jpg"
exif_dict = piexif.load(filename)
new_date = datetime(int(yyyy), int(mm), int(dd), int(h), int(m), 
int(s)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
exif_dict['0th'][piexif.ImageIFD.DateTime] = new_date
exifif_dict['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal] = new_date
exif_dict['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeDigitized] = new_date
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
piexif.insert(exif_bytes, filename)
```

As soon as I try it as a loop it does not work.

```
import PIL.Image

import piexif
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image
#import os
#do not change these:
s = "0"
m = "0"
h = "07"

#change these:
dd = "14"
mm = "07"
yyyy = "2021"
Dir = "D:\Python codes\test"  #insert file directory here##

#run code twice, once for pavement and once for forward photos
name = "-Forward"       #"-Pavement"

#for filename in os.listdir(dir):
for h in range (7,17):
    for m in range (1,61):
        for s in range (1,61):
            if (int(s) < 10):
                s = "0" + str(s)
            if (int(m) < 10):
                m = "0" + str(m)
            if (int(h) < 10):
                h = "0" + str(h)
            else:
                s = int(s)
                m = int(m)
                h = int(h)

            try:
                filename = str(name) + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(yyyy) + "-" + str(h) + "-" + str(m) + "-" + str(s) + ".jpg"
                exif_dict = piexif.load(filename)
                new_date = datetime(int(yyyy), int(mm), int(dd), int(h), int(m), int(s)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
                exif_dict['0th'][piexif.ImageIFD.DateTime] = new_date
                exif_dict['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal] = new_date
                exif_dict['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeDigitized] = new_date
                exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
                piexif.insert(exif_bytes, filename)
                            ##insert right directory
                   # im = Image.open(Dir + name + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(yyyy) + "-" + str(h) + "-" +str(m) + "-" +str(s))
                    #im.save(Dir + name + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(yyyy) + "-" + str(h) + "-" +str(m) + "-" +str(s), exif=exif_bytes, quality="keep", optimize=True)
                s = int(s) + 1
            except:
                s = int(s) + 1
        m = int(m) + 1
    h = int(h) + 1
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? What do you expect and what do you observe instead?

Comment: What i mean is that the photos still do not have a date taken value. I have to add the try and except as the there arent a set ammount of photos eg. -Forward14-07-2021-08-23-25.jpg then -Forward14-07-2021-08-23-26.jpg and so on. so to prevent an error where the filename doesnt exist i have the try and except

Comment: due to the try and except, the program doesnt show me any errors but i dont know how to troubleshoot it

Comment: You can replace the `except` with `except FileNotFoundError`, so other errors won't be ignored.

Comment: If the actual exif manipulating code works, then the problem must be with iterating through file names. A possible way to debug would be to print each filename and check whether the files you need are among them. Furthermore, I suggest you to use something like `os.walk` to iterate over files instead of constructing file paths like this. Also, I suggest you to generally create a backup copy of your files in case your script goes wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thats what I found works well. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more research and found out that the `try:` and `except:` were the problem. The working code can be seen below for those who are interested. Thanks for the help!

```
import PIL.Image
from os import path
import piexif
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image
import os

# do not change these:
s = 0
M = 0
h = 7

# change these:
dd = "14"
mm = "07"
yyyy = "2021"


# run code twice, once for pavement and once for forward photos
name = "-Forward"  # "-Pavement"

# for filename in os.listdir(dir):
for a in range(7, 17):
    M = 0
    for b in range(1, 61):
        s = 0
        for c in range(1, 61):

            ss = str(s)
            MM = str(M)
            hh = str(h)

            if s < 10:
                ss = "0" + str(s)
            if M < 10:
                MM = "0" + str(M)
            if h < 10:
                hh = "0" + str(h)

            filename = str(name) + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(yyyy) + "-" + str(hh) + "-" + str(
                MM) + "-" + str(ss) + ".jpg"

            #try:
            if path.exists(filename):
                # filename = str(name) + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(yyyy) + "-" + str(h) + "-" + str(m) +
                # "-" + str(s) + ".jpg"
                exif_dict = piexif.load(filename)
                new_date = datetime(int(yyyy), int(mm), int(dd), h, M, s).strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
                exif_dict['0th'][piexif.ImageIFD.DateTime] = new_date
                exif_dict['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal] = new_date
                exif_dict['Exif'][piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeDigitized] = new_date
                exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
                piexif.insert(exif_bytes, filename)
                # #insert right directory im = Image.open(Dir + name + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(yyyy) +
                # "-" + str(h) + "-" +str(m) + "-" +str(s)) im.save(Dir + name + str(dd) + "-" + str(mm) + "-" + str(
                # yyyy) + "-" + str(h) + "-" +str(m) + "-" +str(s), exif=exif_bytes, quality="keep", optimize=True)
                s += 1
            #except:
            s += 1
        M += 1
    h += 1
```